# When call volume is high in asterisk, its get killed without any error message

Tags: linux, asterisk, telephony

I am using Asterisk 1.6.2.24 for call handling. I am using 6 port ( 180 channels) to handle the calls. When call volume is around 140 to 150 my asterisk gets killed without any error message even when we enabled the full log in asterisk logger.conf file. 16GB RAM is available in the asterisk running machine. In out of 16GB, 5GB free space also available when asterisk gets killed.

Please let us know what could be the reason?

Comment: Let me know what purpose you put negative mark to my post. If you tell the reason I will correct my mistake in upcoming posting.

Comment: Vote to close off-topic; this is not related to programming Asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: upgrade your asterisk to latest stable.

More complex - find what exactly result core dump

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+debugging

Answer (score 0):

this could be an issue with asterisk itself and you can check in the below link for fix...

https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/ASTERISK-16892